# null submitted value gets converted to 0 under JBoss

Tags: jsf, jboss, null, jboss6.x

I am having a dropdown with list of values and a No Selection option also.Like

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="car" value="#{bean.carId}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Selection "
        itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>                                      
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.carList}" 
        var="cList" itemValue="#{cList.carId}"
        itemLabel="#{cList.carName}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I am selecting No Selection null should get saved in the bean.This is working fine on Tomcat but when I run the same code on Jboss EAP 6.0.1 it is converting the value to '0'.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think that's traitable through the configuration file of the project/application server.

Comment: @Omar which configuration file I should look into?

Comment: it looks like it depends on AS conf files which are numerous.

Comment: Thanks Omar...I fixed it by passing itemValue="null"